# Date upload to Kibana/Elastic not working

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

for the past two days I have been trying to upload a file into Kibana, but without luck. My main problem is that the date is not accepted as a date in Kibana.

My mapping looks like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "Name": {"type": "string","ignore_malformed": true},
        "Country": {"type": "string","ignore_malformed": true}, 
        "Date": {"type": "date", "format": "YYYY-MM-dd" }, 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the string I post via http looks like this

```
{"index": {"_index": "test-index"}} \n{"Type" : "_doc","Name": "David" ,"Country": "UK","Date": 2019-01-29 } \n
```

However every time I try to upload the file I get the following error message

```
"reason" : "Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n
```

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Pass date as string "Date": "2019-01-29", in quotes

Comment: I have tried that, but then they get recognized as a string, instead of a date.

Comment: Can you add mapping after indexing (passing date in quotes)

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Get index/_mapping just need to check if mapping is creted befor indexing or dynamic template is being applied